# Issue in File writing(Takes Much Time) while Capturing Video using CameraX (Video Capture)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-camerax

I am recording video using CameraX some times File Writing Takes much time means about 10s to file writing. Issue is producing in Pixel Devices. Code is Given Below...

```
private fun startCamera() {
    recordingExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    isRecordingStart = false
    hideExoPlayer()
    showAnim()
    binding.tvInterval.text = "3"
    ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this).also {
        it.addListener({
            cameraProvider = it.get()

            val qualitySelector = QualitySelector.from(
                Quality.LOWEST,
                FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(Quality.LOWEST)
            )

            val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
                .setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
                .build()

            videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

            val cameraSelector = when (currentReturnKey) {
                FRONT_VIDEO_CAMERA_KEY -> CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
                else -> CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            }

            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }



            try {
                cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, videoCapture, preview)
                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
                    if (currentReturnKey == REAR_VIDEO_CAMERA_KEY) delay(800)
                    captureVideo()
                }
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                releaseMediaPlayer()
                listener?.onUpdate(currentReturnKey, PCStatus.FAIL)
                updateCameraStatus(currentReturnKey, PCStatus.FAIL)
                initTest()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
}

private fun captureVideo() {

    val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return


    val curRecording = recording
    if (curRecording != null) {
        curRecording.stop()
        recording = null
        return
    }

    outputFile =
        File(getOutputDirectory(), replaceSpaceIntoUnderscore(currentReturnKey) + ".mp4")
    if (outputFile?.exists() == true) {
        val status = outputFile?.delete()
        Log.i("isdelet,", status.toString())
    }


    val mediaStoreOutputOptions = FileOutputOptions
        .Builder(outputFile!!)
        .build()


    isRecordingStart = true
    recording = videoCapture.output
        .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions)
        .apply {
            // Enable Audio for recording
            if (
                PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(
                    this@PCVideoCameraActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                ) ==
                PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                withAudioEnabled()
            }
        }
        .start(recordingExecutor) { recordEvent ->
            when (recordEvent) {

                is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                    runOnUiThread { binding.ivAnimation.gone() }
                    recordingTimer()
                }


                is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                    if (!recordEvent.hasError() || recordEvent.error == VideoRecordEvent.Finalize.ERROR_DURATION_LIMIT_REACHED) {
                        countdownJob?.cancel()
                        recording = null
                        runOnUiThread {
                            showExoPLayer()
                        }

                        Log.i("FinalizeTest", "NoError$outputFile")
                    } else {
                        Log.i("Error", "${recordEvent.cause?.message}")
                        recording?.close()
                        recording = null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and here below code is for timer

```
 private fun recordingTimer() {
        isTimerRunning = true
        countdownJob = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
            val durationMillis =
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3) // Set the duration of the timer in milliseconds
            remainingTimeMillis = durationMillis
            while (remainingTimeMillis > 0) {
                updateTimerText(remainingTimeMillis)
                delay(1000) // Delay for 1 second
                remainingTimeMillis -= 1000
            }
            isTimerRunning = false
            captureVideo()
        }
    }
```

Firstly i was thinking this may be of using Courtines Scope but i have replace it with lifecycler scope but issue is still producing. i donot know which things causing effect on it. bu removing timer fix the issue.

Comment: I would suggest trying out the https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/LifecycleCameraController API. If the issue still exists, you can report it to camerax-developers@android.com, the CameraX team will look into it.

Comment: Actually Recording event creaing delays